# Do Azure Stream analytics process old Azure blob objects or only newly added blob in a container?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-blob-storage

I have a Azure blob container and i will add new blob objects with different name into it on every 15 minutes. And i have Azure Stream Analytics which has a input pointed to that blob container. I am not deleting the old blob files which are processed. So do the Azure Stream Analytics read only un-processed blob objects or even the processed objects?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete old files. Azure Stream Analytics only reads new blob files. The article linked [above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#create-data-stream-input-from-blob-storage) just says that stream analytics looks at a blob just once, it doesn't look for additional changes in the blobs that it already read. What this means is that, all the blob's contents and the blob itself should be made available at the same time. APIs like uploadText, uploadFromStream and PutBlock followed by Commit block, all support this kind of pattern.

Comment: This is not happening.. Azure Stream Analytics is reading old blobs which are already processed in around 45 minutes interval.. But it is reading new blob files immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> do the Azure Stream Analytics read only un-processed blob objects or even the processed objects?

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#create-data-stream-input-from-blob-storage), we can find: ***Stream Analytics will view a blob only once, and any changes that occur in the blob after the job has read the data are not processed***.